# Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345

Tags: docker

When I start a container using this command:

```
sudo docker run -p 18089:8090 -d --name apollo-adminservice-uat \
-v /opt/dabai/app/docker/apollo/apollo-adminservice-uat:/apollo-adminservice \
-v /opt/logs:/opt/logs apollo-adminservice-uat
```

throw this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/apollo-adminservice/scripts/startup.sh\": stat /apollo-adminservice/scripts/startup.sh: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

I am sure this `/apollo-adminservice/scripts/startup.sh` file exits in docker container.I am not sure where is going wrong. How to fix it? Thanks! This is the Docker version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.2
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.8
 Git commit:        6a30dfc
 Built:             Thu Aug 29 05:28:55 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.2
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.8
  Git commit:       6a30dfc
  Built:            Thu Aug 29 05:27:34 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.6
  GitCommit:        894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8
  GitCommit:        425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

This is my docker file:

```
# Dockerfile for apollo-adminservice
# Build with:
# docker build -t apollo-adminservice .
# Run with:
# docker run -p 8090:8090 -d --name apollo-adminservice apollo-adminservice

FROM java:8-jre
MAINTAINER Louis

ENV VERSION 1.4.0

RUN apt-get install unzip

ADD target/apollo-adminservice-${VERSION}-github.zip /apollo-adminservice/apollo-adminservice-${VERSION}-github.zip

RUN unzip /apollo-adminservice/apollo-adminservice-${VERSION}-github.zip -d /apollo-adminservice \
    && rm -rf /apollo-adminservice/apollo-adminservice-${VERSION}-github.zip \
    && mv /apollo-adminservice/apollo-adminservice-${VERSION}-github/* /apollo-adminservice \
    && sed -i '$d' /apollo-adminservice/scripts/startup.sh \
    && echo "tail -f /dev/null" >> /apollo-adminservice/scripts/startup.sh

EXPOSE 8090

CMD ["/apollo-adminservice/scripts/startup.sh"]
```

Comment: Show your dockerfile

Comment: You hide everything in `/apollo-adminservice` with a `docker run -v` option.  I'd delete that.